Can I call CreateString inline when creating a table?
Assuming following table in flatbuffers:
table Person {
  id:int32
  name:string;
  age:int16;
  location:string;
}

Then in c++ code, are both of these approaches correct?
//Calling CreateString inline
auto person = CreatePerson(builder,
                           10,
                           builder.CreateString(name),
                           25,
                           builder.CreateString("New York"));

vs
auto name = builder.CreateString("John");
auto loc = builder.CreateString("New York");

auto person = CreatePerson(builder, 10, name, 25, loc);

Reason I'm asking is because we're supposed to create all offsets before creating the table but documentation doesn't clearly state if inline CreateString call is acceptable?

I don't know flatbuffers, so I don't know if following is a problem, but for the "inline call", order of evaluation is not guaranteed, so  builder.CreateString("New York") can be called before builder.CreateString(name).

Unless the call to builder.CreateString has some kind of side effect then those two options are the same. The requirement to calculate all offsets before creating the table is met either way because C++ guarantees that all arguments will be evaluated before a function is called.

Both codes are valid. The argument evaluation order is unimportant. builder just serializes single values at free spaces in a byte array. CreatePerson(builder, 10, name, 25, loc) copies serialized data from builder.
